# What happened with my answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

While on Stack Overflow, I have noticed the number of posts I wrote is lower than the number of posts I remember. I remember that I wrote the 300th answer on September 24th, but suddenly it is showing only 298 answers; I also remember I have already given more than 310 answers.

What was wrong with my answers on Stack Overflow?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: They were, perhaps, not answers and/or bad answers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *really* want to go there? OK, then…

Here's just a few examples:

1. The complete content of [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android/7544717#7544717) was:

   > Just check an issue [WebView has no way to call JavaScript from Java](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=742) at code.google.com

   When an answer contains nothing useful besides a link elsewhere, it should be a comment, not an answer. I made it a comment.
2. [Your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340654/android-best-way-to-load-images-in-background/7538272#7538272) was:

   > The concept you need to implement is known as "ListView - Image Lazy Loading" and here is the best example i have ever found: [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) , just check this.

   Another one I turned into a comment. Personally, though, I think answers that just say, "look at this other SO question" should instead be votes to "close as duplicate."
3. [Your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604657/json-decoding-in-android/7551342#7551342) consisted solely of:

   > Here i have posted an example for "Android - JSON Parsing example" which may be helpful to understand JSON Parsing easily.

   where "Android - JSON Parsing example" linked to your blog. I deleted it, along with a number of other answers that were solely self-links.

None of these added any real value to Stack Overflow.

I suspect now that you've brought this to the community's attention, quite a few of your other answers are about to start getting flagged as well.

Comment: Ok thanx. But i dont know ,i am just trying my best to helping out others unknowingly, this happened to me first time so i dont know about this kind of deletion(without any notification) rule. Atleast SO moderators should send notification that these answers has been deleted due to the particular reason. Otherwise Thanx

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani - When someone's been a SO user for over a year and has over 6K in rep, I assume that they know the rules on SO. When they also have a flag weight of 30 and 27% of their answers have been deleted (110 out of your actual 408—and no, not all were by me today!), I figure that they've made the choice to ignore them. Did you really need an email to tell you that spam is not welcome here?

Comment: surprised to know this today, sorry for my bad words mentioned above, but really i am rapidly trying to answers as many as i can, i know i have read FAQ and also suggested to past, also heard about reputation revoke from my friend. But dont know about this actually.

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani: You only have a few posts flagged for moderator attention, two you flagged yourself.  Ironically, if you had gotten more flags, a moderator would have contacted you privately about this.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ i didn't got what you tried to say exactly. sorry

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani: Normally, in this situation, you would have been attracting flags.  A moderator would have acted on the flags and probably would have contacted you by a private message in order to explain what happened.  That was not what happened here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dori you have moderated my one of answer as "rmv spam" even user has commented as "Thanks a lot.Exactly what i wanted." ,what's wrong with this? Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242661/enter-data-in-edittext-and-respond-without-pressing-enter/6242778#6242778

Comment: Even this is also moderated as "rmv spam", now i have just tried to answer with the possible way of solution and it should be implement to achieve the desired result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786521/accessing-tourarray-values-in-a-different-activity/6786906#6786906

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani - I'm not clear on what your last comment is saying or asking. Yes, I used "rmv spam" as an edit reason; that's what happens when you have *that* many answers that contain nothing but a link to your blog. Re [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242778#6242778): besides the linkspam, it also included useful info, which is why the OP said thanks and why I didn't delete it outright. The same reasoning applied [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6786906#6786906), as well.

Answer (score 11):

See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question
>   may be removed**. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - not even a *partial* answer to the actual question
>
> If you wish to improve an existing answer, click edit. For additional guidance,
>   see [How to Answer](/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I guess a bunch of questions (on which you have posted answers) has been deleted. Thus, your answers has been deleted as well.